# Twitter Typeahead.js remote data

Tags: jquery, json, typeahead.js

Is there a way to customize typeahead for it to fetch data from different json depending on the input field's cursor position.

For instance when searching the term " black paneled hat" When the user start typing  black it would fetch from colors.json and when the user finish entering colors and hits the spacebar it starts fetching from style.json and when the user hits space and start typing hat it fetched from category.json

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not possible for you, but it seems to me that this would be simpler to implement on the server.  So all type ahead requests go to search.json and that endpoint examines the search string and calls the appropriate method.